# What command to search for ID in .bz2 file?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I am new to Linux and I'm trying to look for an ID number within a .bz2 file. Seems like a fairly straight forward requirement, however I cannot find the correct command anywhere online. I believe I need to use bzgrep.

**I want to look for '123456' in the file Bulk9876.bz2**

How would I construct this command?

Comment: Have you tried `bzgrep 123456 Bulk9876.bz2`?

Comment: Yep, it doesn't return anything, however if I do bzgrep 9876 Bulk9876.bz2 (or something in the file name) then it returns:

**Binary file (standard input) matches**.

I don't think it's actually searching inside the file.

Comment: It would seem, then, that you have a non-standard version of `bzgrep`, or you have an alias/function/script that masks the real one. What does `type bzgrep` tell you?

Comment: "bzgrep is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/bzgrep"

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to tell grep that it's okay to parse that data as text:

```
bzgrep -a 123456 Bulk9876.bz2
```

If you're trying to view the compressed data (rather than decompressing it and searching the decompressed data), just use `grep -a …`.

Otherwise, it might make sense to verify that the desired string is even present in the file; bunzip2 it and `grep -a` the decompressed file.  If that works, the problem is in your bzgrep instance (which is odd because it should be using the same decompression library as bunzip2).

Comment: This command didn't return anything, and I cannot get the file to unzip it. I have limited access.

Comment: You can't read the file?  I'm not following.  What's the output of `ls -lh Bulk9876.bz2; id`?  If the bzgrep command gave no output at all, that implies it successfully scanned the file and failed to find the given pattern (`123456`).  Just to be sure, run `echo $?` after that command.  I'm expecting a response of `1`, but a higher number means there was an error (and a `0` means there was a match).